# Using turtle graphics in Google colab

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics, google-colaboratory

I am working with a student that uses Google colab. I tried introducing her to turtle graphics. We got this error: TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable.
When I try to look up the error all the solutions are very specific to matplotlib. That worked for my student without making any adjustment. 
I am looking for a solution for this that works more generally or at least works with turtle and tkinter.

Student is using a Chrome book. Google colab is what she uses at school, solving the problem in that environment would be best if possible. Did try to create a Turtle object, but this produced the same error.
I did a search on the error all the post I could find talked bout this problem with matplotlib. The solution in that case was to override what I think is a rendering option by invoking .use('Agg'). I did not see an obvious equivalent for turtle.
I also tried using matplotlib, to see if we got the error that I saw in the postings. We tried a simple matplotlib example and it worked without any changes. The graph output appeared as expected.

import turtle
turtle.forward(100)

I expect the turtle graphics to be drawn in the results.

### What I actually got were these errors:

TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 turtle.forward(100)

5 frames
/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/**init**.py in **init**(self, screenName, baseName, className, useTk, sync, use)
   2021                 baseName = baseName + ext
   2022         interactive = 0
-> 2023         self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
   2024         if useTk:
   2025             self._loadtk()

TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Answer (score 12):

Turtle for Google Colab notebooks
Installation for Google Colab:
Create an empty code cell and type:

```
!pip3 install ColabTurtle
```

Run the code cell.

Usage
In any code cell, import like following:

```
from ColabTurtle.Turtle import *
```

As Colab stores the declared variables in the runtime, call this before using:

```
initializeTurtle()
```

Answer (score 11):

Create an empty code cell, type the following pip command and run it:

```
!pip3 install ColabTurtle
```

I recommend you use your turtle like this (in a separate code piece):

```
import ColabTurtle.Turtle as lia
lia.initializeTurtle(initial_speed=5) 
lia.color('blue')
lia.forward(100)
lia.right(45)
lia.color('red')
lia.forward(50)
```

You may in fact use direct calls (skip all the lia object ref), but it's not a good idea IMHO since you want your students to get used to using instances. This simplified (less recommended way) would look like this:

```
import ColabTurtle
forward(100)
right(90)
forward(100)
```

You are not habituating students to using objects and
they cannot see the tool tips (e.g. available methods and properties of the object).

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using https://repl.it/ to teach Turtle (there's a specific option to do just that).

Answer (score 0):

Turtle use Tk as a Window display. But Colab server is on the internet, it cannot open a new window on your machine and send display there. So, you cannot (easily) use Turtle on Colab.

If you really want to, there a hard way where you use virtual display, and capture screen to display. But I think it's too hard.

If you want to teach turtle to them on the browser, there's one implemented in JavaScript here.

https://rawgit.com/wrschneider99/js-turtle/master/turtle.html