# Creating a screen on python (turtle)

Tags: python, import, screen, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

For an assignment, I have to create a turtle program on python which uses recursion to draw a shape.

However, I am unable to even create the necessary screen to draw any shapes on.
I am currently using Google Collab.

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
```

Is what my program looks like right now, I have turtle installed and I have searched everywhere for alternate solutions to creating a screen but every line I have found more or less has the same line, which doesn't work for me.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: did you find [using-turtle-graphics-in-google-colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56876886/using-turtle-graphics-in-google-colab) and did it help?

Comment: https://www.linuxtut.com/en/e0039b79619306f63bf0/   , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5IHp1peG-xM    ,    https://colab.research.google.com/github/karinjd/CSCI5525/blob/master/Turtle.ipynb   - plenty of resources on good old google: `python turtle google colab example` as search keys... did you check them? did they help?

Comment: If nothing of the above helped, [mre] + stacktrace and/or better error description

Comment: Thank you Patrick Artner, I watched one of the youtube videos that you tagged and it helped alot!! I was able to generate a screen :)

Comment: Here is my ColabTurtle notebook. Hope it will help.  
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KMk72MX5igJiWGEZkIdvEzIZ7kg-hPo9

Answer (score 0):

You are using collab. Collab does not work with turtle unless you have an environment. I suggest PyCharm or the built - in python editor IDLE. Also, you forgot to make a screen. Make the screen under the import.

```
screen = turtle.screen()
```

Then, if you are using PyCharm, type this at the end of your program.

```
screen.exitonclick()
```